# Populate Highcharts X-Axis With Dates Given a From And To Date

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

How it is possible to populate the x axis with dates given a 'from' and 'to' date values?

Essentially, the user will enter a "from" and "to" date in my HTML web interface; for example, `24/08/2011 - 28/08/2011`

This will be via HTML textfields whose values are caught using jQuery when a user presses a "View Graph" button.

I would like to create a spline chart whose x-axis starts 2 days before the "from" date and ends 2 days after the "to" date.

So in the example above, user provides:

```
from -> 24/08/2011
to   -> 28/08/2011
```

therefore

```
x-axis start -> 22/08/2011
x-axis ends  -> 30/08/2011
```

I also want it to have 24 hour intervals displayed as their corresponding dates. The x-axis should therefore look something like this:

```
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|___________________________________________________ 
   |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 
 22/08 23/08 24/08 25/08 26/08 27/08 28/08 29/08 30/08
```

EDIT:

I found the following code:

```
series: [{
         type: 'spline',
         name: 'USD to EUR',
         pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 10,
         pointStart: Date.UTC(<?php echo($year); ?>, 0, <?php echo($day);?>),
         data: [
            0.8446, 0.8445, 0.8444
     ]
      }]
```

But I just cannot figure out how HighCharts equates time intervals to the parts of data..I know obviously it has to do with pointInterval...

I can guess that 24 * 3600 is the number of seconds in a day but what is the * 10? How do I get it to display exactly 24 hour intervals?

Comment: Ultra-vague question. Need MOAR INFOZ

Comment: You understand your problem, but we don't :) Walk away for ten minutes then look at this again, then edit it to include a bit more context. I know it's hard to ask when you're in the middle of something and have a heightened sense of urgency.

Comment: @Tim, what do you need me to explain? I have the min and max ranges provided to me at the front end. I want to feed these into highcharts and set the intervals as days and auto populate the in between dates...

Comment: @user559142, you just explained it :) Perhaps that might be a good edit to your question? If you describe (a bit better) what you want to achieve, you'll probably get more answers (and less flags).

Answer (score 10):

Here are some references that should help you out.

- [Highcharts API xAxis](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis)

Also created a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DP634/) to help you start out.

**xAxis**

```
xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%m-%d'   
    },
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    min: Date.UTC(<?php echo $date_from;?>),
    max: Date.UTC(<?php echo $date_to;?>)
}
```

Basically, what this does is set the type of xAxis to 'datetime' so the `tickInterval` understands that's it is incrementing by `86400000 milliseconds`, and also set the format of the xAxis based on the required [date format](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#highcharts-object). 
Then the `$date_from` and `$date_to` should look like this from `PHP` handling the form submission.

```
$date_from = date("Y, m, d",strtotime($_POST['from']) - 2*86400);
$date_to = date("Y, m, d",strtotime($_POST['to']) + 2*86400);
```

Comment: i'm working on higcharts now with a date range picker. I was going to use AJAX to make new calls for json arrays remove and reset the data. Using the method in your answer is it possible for me to load all data into the series, then set the min max date to what is in my date range picker and redraw the table or refresh it?

Comment: @Anagio You may look up their API, I guess this should work for you, [http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw()). Yes, I think you can load the changes and update the correct fields/parameters (not the actual DOM for the chart) and then redraw it.